# android studio- webservice request from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i work on android studio and i want to send a request to a rest Web Service server.
when i do a request from the "MainActivity.java" its work perfectly, but on a fragment, my app crash.
this is my request on the main activity:

```
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    try {//json format
        sum += "00";
        obj.put("terminalNumber",terminalNumber);
        obj.put("user","noamtest");
        obj.put("password","i2zbvOws");
        obj.put("shopNumber","001");
        obj.put("currency","1");
        obj.put("creditCard",card);
        obj.put("creditCardDateMmYy", date);
        obj.put("total",sum);
        obj.put("id",id);
        obj.put("cvv",cvv);
    Log.i("requesr",obj.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button
    AndroidNetworking.post("https://gateway20.pelecard.biz/services/DebitRegularType")//send the json object to the method
            .addJSONObjectBody(obj)
            .setTag("test")
            .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
            .build()
            .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    extract=response;

                    responsdebit=response.optString("StatusCode")+" "+response.optString("ErrorMessage");
                    Log.i("respons",responsdebit);
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(ANError error) {
                    // handle error
                }

            });
```

and this one is on my fragment:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();


            try {//json format

                obj.put("terminalNumber",terminalNumber);
                obj.put("user",username);
                obj.put("password",pass);
                obj.put("intIn","B45804580458045804580c100j2");
                Log.i("test",obj.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button
            AndroidNetworking.post("https://gateway20.pelecard.biz/services/DebitbyIntIn")//send the json object to the method
                    .addJSONObjectBody(obj)
                    .setTag("test")
                    .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
                    .build()
                    .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            String s=response.optString("ResultData");
                            Log.i("test",s);

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onError(ANError error) {
                            // handle error
                        }
                    });
```

i try to call a method from the main activity and its work but i prefer to send the request from the fragment.

Comment: In the fragment, in what lifecycle method you send the request ? It should be in onStart https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Creating

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: @RaymondChenon but i would like to send the request when someone click a buttom.
now the onclick method is in the oncreate method